# How can I plot my probability distribution function?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

The PDF of random variable $Z$ is given by

$$f_{Z}(z)=\hspace{-2mm}\int \limits_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{2m-1}\exp\left(-\frac{mz^2}{\sigma}\right)}{\Gamma(m)\sigma^m}\frac{2m^m}{\sqrt{2\pi}\zeta\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln \sigma-\mu)^2}{2\zeta^2}\right)d\sigma$$.

Let $m=2$, $\mu=0.6931$ and $\zeta=0.9240$. How can I plot this PDF?

I tried this:

```
μ = 0.6931;
ζ = 0.9240;
m = 2;

f[z_] :=
  Integrate[
    (z^(2*m - 1)*Exp[-m*z^2/σ]*(2*m^m)*
      Exp[-(Log[σ] - μ)^2/(2*ζ^2)]/(Gamma[m]*σ^m*Sqrt[2*π]*ζ*σ)), 
    {σ, 0, Infinity}]

Dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[z], {z, 0, Infinity}];

pdfH[z] := PDF[Dist, z];

Plot[pdfH, {z, 0, 5}];
```

It does not work.

Furthermore, if $X$ is a random variable which is given by $X = Z^2$, then how to draw the PDF of $X$?

Comment: How would you plot anything? Your syntax of `Plot` is wrong, you suppress the output of the command (the actual plot), and you are generally confusing `=` and `:=` definitions. Please start by reading the manual http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot

Comment: I don't think this is a well posed PDF. Doing the integration of the PDF numerically, `f[z_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(z^(2*m - 1)*Exp[-m*z^2/\[Sigma]]*2*m^m*
    Exp[-(Log[\[Sigma]] - \[Mu])^2/(2*\[Sigma]^2)]/(Gamma[m]*\[Sigma]^
        m*Sqrt[2*\[Pi]]*\[Zeta]*\[Sigma])), {\[Sigma], 0, Infinity}]`, allows for direct evaluation for particular `z`. However, for the PDF to be valid, the integral of the PDF over the domain of `z` must be equal to one. Here assuming $z \in \left[0,\infty\right]$, that is not the case. For the integral of the PDF to be 1, the upper bound of z is 2.5178.

Comment: @Marchi, how do you find the upper bound of z? Would you please show me the way. If we fix the upper limit of z to the above value, is it possible to draw the PDF then?

Comment: Your Mathematica code expressing the integral does not correspond to your MathJax expression giving the integral.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I think it is correct now.

Comment: @Marchi, there was a typo it the Mathematica code. Will you please check it again now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Irrespective of the discussion if this is a well defined PDF, the issue why you don't get a plot is because the `Integrate` in the definition of `f` can not be calculated analytically. You need a numerical integral, as already suggested by Marchi:

```
μ = 0.6931;
ζ = 0.9240;
m = 2;

f[z_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(z^(2*m - 1)*Exp[-m*z^2/σ]*(2*m^m)*
    Exp[-(Log[σ] - μ)^2/(2*ζ^2)]/(Gamma[m]*σ^
        m*Sqrt[2*π]*ζ*σ)), {σ, 0, Infinity}]

Dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[z], {z, 0, Infinity}];

pdfH[z_] := PDF[Dist, z];
Plot[pdfH[z], {z, 0, 5}]
```

Note the `z` in `Dist` is not the same as the `z` in `Plot`. Therefore, using pattern matching and `SetDelayed` are important to not confuse the two.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I get a blank plot with the above Mathematica code..

Comment: Did you use a fresh kernel? Or at least after a `ClearAll`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting it now. I really appreciate it very much.

Comment: Shouldn't this work? `NExpectation[x, x \[Distributed] Dist]` ? Given that this does : `NIntegrate[x pdfH[x] , {x, 0, Infinity}]`